# Microsoft TFS build process, how to run multiple scripts as Pre-build script

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I am new to TFS. I see under "Edit Build Definition->Process->Build", we are able to configure the script to be executed before build. And when we click on the browse button, the pop out window only allows us to select one file. I wonder is there any way to add multiple files as Pre-build script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just have one master script that the build calls, then call your other scripts from the master one.

Comment: Thanks Dylan, so great to have an answer from Microsoft support here :)